# Visual Studio Task Runner Explorer with Gruntfile.js that is not in the root folder

Tags: visual-studio, gruntjs

Is there a way to make Visual Studio's Task Runner Explorer detect a Gruntfile.js that is not in the root directory of the project? My gruntfile is in a folder in the root folder but I can't make the task runner see it. If I move it to the root it does see it but I don't want to do that since the whole existing infrastructure for the project fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like currently the Task Runner Explorer does not work unless the gruntfile is in the root folder. According to the [description](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) it is a known issue.